# How add subviews to UIPageViewController with autolayout ( constraints)?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I try to add the UIImageView to UIPageVC background view, but it will be as subview, because it will have an auto layout by constraints.

I tried to do something like this in UIPageViewController class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dataSource = self
    delegate = self

    // Adding an UIImageView to background

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "backgoundImage"))
    imageView!.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    view.insertSubview(imageView!, at: 0)
}
```

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this to ad constraints.

```
if let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "backgoundImage")) {
  imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
  view.insertSubview(imageView, at: 0)

  imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

  imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
  imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
  imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
  imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: there is a trouble with adding any constraint to `self.view` 
I will get this error message and add it to question, but thanks for answer, I will try to use it!

Comment: Yeap, it works. Thanks!
But in `if if let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "backgoundImage"))` there is no optional value, I changed this to `let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "backgroundView"))`

Comment: @GolovanovDmitrii Actually it should be `UIImage(named: "backgoundImage")`

Comment: I do the if block like:   
`if let image = UIImage(named: "backgroundView") { }`